# Como acessar um item em um array de objetos?

Tags: javascript, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

Estou pegando informações do banco de dados e colocando em um array:
(mais detalhes do código)

```
var alunos = {};
var self = 0;

function sortearAluno(){

    var dataForm = {'tipo': "listar"};
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        data: dataForm,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'alunoDAO.php',
        success: function(dados){
            var alunos = {};
            for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
                        self++;
                        alunos['a'+self] = {            
                            idAluno : dados[i].idAluno,
                            nome: dados[i].nome,
                            classe : dados[i].classe,
                            hp : dados[i].hp,
                            ap : dados[i].ap,
                            xp : dados[i].xp,
                        }; 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Até aqui está normal, quando eu executo o código ele consegue criar.

Console no Chrome:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas então, quando eu tento pegar os valores das keys, eu não consigo. Já tentei de várias formas, procurei em todas as páginas que o google me mostrou, mas não achei nada que funcionasse.

Algumas das minhas tentativas:

```
console.log(alunos.a1)
```

Exibe = "undefined"

```
console.log(alunos[a1].nome)
```

Exibe = "Uncaught ReferenceError: a1 is not defined"

Entre outras coisas que tentei. Então, alguém sabe como resolver isso ou tem alguma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Comment: O que aparece com `console(alunos['a1'].nome)`?

Comment: Será que estás a criar esse objeto dentro da callback do ajax e a usar fora dela? Podes mostrar mais código e um exemplo do conteúdo de `dados`?

Comment: @VictorStafusa Para sua informação, indexar um objeto com **`.`** é o mesmo que indexar um objeto computadamente com **`[...]`**, a diferença é que com o **`.`** você só pode declarar um identificador válido do ECMAScript, portanto o mesmo que indexar um objeto com uma **`String`**. Ou seja, vai acontecer quase o mesmo erro se você tentar fazer uma expressão como **`alunos['a1'].nome`** em vez de **`alunos[a1].nome`**, o erro vai ser diferente porque você está declarando uma String na indexação, por exemplo: **`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nome' of undefined`**

Comment: Victor, aparece " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nomeP' of undefined".

Comment: Sergio, atualizai a publicação com mais partes do codigo

Comment: Ae pessoal tentei fazer o como o Victor disse dentro do callback do ajax como o Sergio comentou e  funcionou.Imaginei que por ter declarado o alunos fora da função e adicionar os dados e depois usar essa mesma variável daria certo, mas parece que não. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```js
var dados = [
{
    idAluno : "1",
    nome: "Pedro",
    classe : "A1",
    hp : "3",
    ap : "5",
    xp : "1"
}, {
    idAluno : "1",
    nome: "Carlos",
    classe : "A1",
    hp : "8",
    ap : "7",
    xp : "1"
}, {
    idAluno : "3",
    nome: "José",
    classe : "A1",
    hp : "3",
    ap : "3",
    xp : "8"
}
]

var alunos = {};

for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){
var key = 'a' + String(i);

alunos[key] = {
    idAluno : dados[i].idAluno,
    nome: dados[i].nome,
    classe : dados[i].classe,
    hp : dados[i].hp,
    ap : dados[i].ap,
    xp : dados[i].xp,
};
}

document.write(alunos['a1'].nome)
```

Comment: Olá Emir Marques já havia conseguido, é isso mesmo, o que estava dando errado no meu é que eu estava tentando usar a variável fora do método ajax, imaginei que por ter criado ela fora do método, e adicionado os valores dentro do método ajax, em qualquer outro método eu teria acesso, mas parece que não, é só eu fazer tudo no mesmo método que funciona, mas mesmo assim obrigado!